# Invalid binary on iOs 4 app submission

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to submit an iOs 4 binary and get "We do not accept applications built with this version of SDK" message.

I build with 
XCode 3.2.3 iPhone 4 GM Seed
iPhone 4 based SDK
iPhone/iPad as a target family
iPhone 3.0 as a target deployment family

Comment: IIRC, iPhone OS 4 is still under NDA - so you will have to ask on Apples Forums

Comment: ANd also with the Beta builds i dont think u can build for 3.0...thats why u shoudl install beta stuff in a different directory than your orginal xcode